# Toroidal transformers

Tags: rf, transformer, design

In regards to the design of toridal transformers is there any **specific book** that can be referred to?

**Can toroidal transformers be built for high power application?** I mean can v built a 25 KVA , 11KV-433V toroidal transformer.

**Are toroidal transformers limited to RF applications only?**

*These are a few questions running on my mind, hoping it would be answered soon.*

Comment: This question is actually 3 questions, which will make it difficult for someone to conclusively answer. Please consider narrowing the scope of what you're asking, or divide this into multiple separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment about books or high voltages uses.

I can say though that toroidal transformers aren't just limited to RF applications. I've seen them used quite a lot in power supplies for audio amplifiers.

Answer (score 1):

The physical shape of a transformer core has little to do with the frequency or power you want to use it for. I've got an iron core laminated toroidal transformer that is 500VA rated and used for AC power; it wouldn't work at high frequencies because the iron losses would be too high. On the other hand I've seen ferrite cored toroidal transformers that are a few inches across and can "transport" kilowatts but only at higher frequencies such as several kilohertz and above.

I guess one of the things about ferrite toroids is that they can be easily manufactured and they have very magnetic coupling factors between primary and secondary (up to 99%) and this means lower losses in switch mode supplies.

It sounds like you have a power AC application in mind and ideally you want materials with high magnetic permeability and materials that are robust and this probably limits you to iron (silicon steel) laminate materials.